# The URL '/session' did not map to a valid resource | How to run desktop application test using winAppDriver / windows application driver using java?

Tags: java, appium, windows, winappdriver

I'm trying to run automate test for windows calculator app on windows10 using **Windows application driver (winAppDriver)**, **appium** and **java** as below example:  https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/Java/CalculatorTest, but when I run the test after started the appium getting below mentioned error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The URL '/session' did not map to a valid resource
Command duration or timeout: 204 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'LKXXXX', ip: '10.88.68.53', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
```

My code is as below:

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

public class CalculatorTest {

    private static IOSDriver CalculatorSession = null;
    private static WebElement CalculatorResult = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
            CalculatorSession = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
            CalculatorSession.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            CalculatorSession.findElementByName("Clear").click();
            CalculatorSession.findElementByName("Seven").click();
            CalculatorResult = CalculatorSession.findElementByName("Display is  7 ");
            Assert.assertNotNull(CalculatorResult);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

***My Dev Environment***

- Windows 10 (Developer mode enabled)
- appium v1.6.5
- java v1.8
- winappdriver v0.9-beta
- IDE - Eclipse

I will be glad if anyone can help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After long research, I have found the answer for the above question. We can solve this using two methods.

> ***NOTE:*** You should start either *appium server* **or** *winappdriver.exe*. Don't try to run both appium and winappdriver at once by your self.

1. **If you are starting appium server**, you should give the URI as well as below following by the IP and port;

   `CalculatorSession = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`
2. **If you are running the winappdriver.exe directly,** you should give only the IP and the port of winappdriver as below;

   `CalculatorSession = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);`

Comment: Let me add the info here, as I stumbled upon it: To use WinAppDriver you need to run it as Admin and to activate Developer Mode in Windows Settings.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @Vijendran Selvarajah at first.

for this example：http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/
need add this line `path: "/wd/hub"`

```js
// javascript

const wdio = require("webdriverio");
const assert = require("assert");

const opts = {
  port: 4723,
  path: "/wd/hub", // fix: The URL '/session' did not map to a valid resource
  capabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    platformVersion: "8",
    deviceName: "Android Emulator",
    app: "/path/to/the/downloaded/ApiDemos.apk",
    appPackage: "io.appium.android.apis",
    appActivity: ".view.TextFields",
    automationName: "UiAutomator2"
  }
};

async function main () {
  const client = await wdio.remote(opts);

  const field = await client.$("android.widget.EditText");
  await field.setValue("Hello World!");
  const value = await field.getText();
  assert.equal(value,"Hello World!");

  await client.deleteSession();
}

main();
```

I will share a completed doc and zip in the feature about how to use Appium to test Android App with all deps.

Answer (score 2):

to my testing, the calculator app in windows doesn't open when you giving the system path you have to use
**Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App**

and you don't need to open appium sever has appium has the older version of winappdriver(0.7)

and just saying the winappdriver server should be running in the background

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I have found the correct way. Please refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

for appium 2.0 it can be fixed by removing "/" after port.
eg :
appium_url = "http://0.0.0.0:4723"